# MinGW can't be installed on Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, compiler-errors, mingw, mingw32

I am trying to install MinGW but it's always failing to install. See the picture for the error message.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAFLq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow! My name is Alex and I will try my best to fix this problem of yours.

First, do you have a firewall running? Try running it as an Administrator.

If those didn't work, then I believe it's to the sourgeforge or the network itself. This is probably temporary and will be fixed so I suggest you try it later.

Good luck!

Comment: I tried after turning off the Firewall as well as running it as an Administrator, but it couldn't install still.

Comment: Hello @Saurav,

If the issue persist and you cannot download, then it is to the network. Try this:

`1. Open command prompt as an administrator`
`2. Type ipconfig /flushdns`

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot comment, I suppose there is no other way than write an answer. I am having the same issue and it seems to be related to the automated installer, it appears to be broken. Try installing manually (download the zip and manually place in correct directories and set system paths).